# how to translate preg_match_all results with qtranslate plugin in wordpress?

Tags: preg-match-all, shortcode, qtranslate

I'd really need some help on this one.

I have a function to extract the content between the shortcodes `[internet]blablabla[/internet]` done by `preg_match_all`

```
function get_content($my_post) {
      $post_id = $my_post; //$_GET["p"];
      $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
      $title = $queried_post->post_title;

      preg_match_all('#\[internet\](.+)\[\/internet\]#', $queried_post->post_content, $matches);
      //var_dump($matches[1][0]);

      if ( is_single( ) ) {
      echo '<br><br><h1>'.$matches[1][0].'</h1>';
      echo '<br><br><a href="http://moldcell.info/ts/?p='.$my_post.'&amp;'.$matches[1][0].'">get url</a>';


   }

   }
```

My website is in 3 languages (English, Romanian, Russian). When I put the conditional tags of `qtranslate`, it doesn't translate, but it gives me the value of the default language.

How can I make it translate?

Thank you in advance.

**P.S.**: I've posted this in the qtranslate support forum, but no reply. Maybe the SO people could help me.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the answer:

```
echo '<br><br><a href="http://moldcell.info/ts/?p='.$my_post.'&amp;'.$matches[1][1].'">get url</a>';
```

or

```
echo '<br><br><a href="http://moldcell.info/ts/?p='.$my_post.'&amp;'.$matches[1][2].'">get url</a>';
```